# Saving ListData Objects with onSavedInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an app that has one main `Activity` that swaps out numerous `Fragment`'s.  Well it doesn't matter what `Fragment` you are on, after low memory kills the `Activity` and you try to return to the app, it boots you back to the "start" `Fragment` that the `Activity` first calls.  (Note:  Almost all of these are actually `ListFragment`'s)

**So here are my questions:**

Should I be using `onSaveInstanceState()` in EACH Fragment? And if so, am I saving the *Data* in the Fragment OR the Fragment *itself*?  Or do you use `onSaveInstanceState()` only once in the Main `Activity`.  (If this is even the course to take)

Note:  I have  `setRetainInstance(true)` but I don't think I am handling that correctly, if that is the solution.  These are all put as the last line of `onActivityCreated()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends a lot on how you are managing fragments.

I'll assume you are not using the Fragment backstack, and that you have called setRetainInstance(true) on EACH fragment.

You need to use a tag when you attach the fragments.

In Activity#onSaveInstanceState() you need to remember which fragments are visible.

In Activity#onCreate you need to find the existing Fragments by tag for each fragment, then create new instances of any Fragments you can't find.   Now you can use the information from the saved instance state to make the appropriate Fragments visible (show or add or replace as necessary depending on how your code manages the fragments.)

Edit in response to questions/comments:

- activty.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag); finds an existing fragment
- in a Fragment transaction: add(fragment, tag), replace(id, fragment, tag), etc. lets you specify the tag.   You can also put it in a layout file using the attribute

  - class=".myFrag$tag"

The actual fragment object including its contents still exist when you use setRetainInstance.

Note: If you don't want to use tags, you may also use the fragment manager's putFragment/getFragment methods to put the fragment into the instance state bundle.

Finally you can simply let the fragment save itself by calling FragmentManager's saveFragmentInstanceState but I've had trouble using this correctly.

Comment: Your first two assumptions are correct.  Can you show a very basic code sample of assigning a tag to a fragment - does this happen during the `FragmentTransaction`? or elsewhere? Also, code sample on the `onCreate` part as well in finding the existing Fragments?  Last question:  does doing it this way save the actual data IN the Fragment as well?